# TicTacToe Java check for draw

Tags: java, intellij-idea, draw, tic-tac-toe

In my TicTacToe game I have a method which checks if someone wins and this works perfectly. But the methode for checking if there is a draw doesn't work. At first it checks if there is a winner and when not it should check if there's a draw. As soon as every 9 places are played in the field the message "it's draw" doesn't appear. I can't find the mistake.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("welcome!");
                playerMove(gameBoard);
                if (checkIfCurrentPlayerIsWinner(gameBoard, 'X')) {
                    System.out.println("Player won the game!");
                    playerScore++;
                    break;
if (checkDraw(gameBoard)) {
                    System.out.println("It's a draw!");
                    tieScore++;
                    break;
                }
 private static boolean checkDraw(char[][] gameBoard){
        for(int i = 1; i< 10; i++){
            if(getFieldContent(gameBoard, i) != ' '){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
public static char getFieldContent(char[][] gameboard, int fieldNumber) {

        switch (fieldNumber) {
            case 1:
                return gameboard[0][0];
            case 2:
                return gameboard[0][2];
            case 3:
                return gameboard[0][4];
            case 4:
                return gameboard[2][0];
            case 5:
                return gameboard[2][2];
            case 6:
                return gameboard[2][4];
            case 7:
                return gameboard[4][0];
            case 8:
                return gameboard[4][2];
            case 9:
                return gameboard[4][4];
        }
        return ' ';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inferring here that `gameboard` initially contains all spaces and that you've for some reason decided to only store moves in its even indices. I'll note also that your code is missing some closing braces (`}`s). Please in the future only post code that compiles, or if compilation is your problem, indicate such.

In any event, `checkDraw` returns `false` if all of the tested indices in `gameboard` are *not* `' '` and `true` otherwise. It seems like what you want to test for is the opposite, i.e. that the entire board has been played on, i.e. no *non-space* cells exist. That being the case, `checkDraw` would look something like the following:

```java
private static boolean checkDraw(char[][] gameBoard) {
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        // note that the test is now == instead of !=
        if(getFieldContent(gameBoard, i) == ' ') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // no non-space cells were found, so the entire board has been
    // played out, resulting in a draw, provided that a separate
    // winner check has already been conducted
    return true;
}
```